# $u \in L^{\infty}(0,T;H^{1})$, What does this notation mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, finite-element-method

I am trying to understand the error analysis for a mixed finite element method. I am told $u$ must be in the above space, but this notation is unclear to me.

Answer (score 2):

This mean that $u(t), 0\leq t \leq T$ is a function, and for each fixed $t$, $u(t)\in H^1$. There may be a defined norm in $H^1$, say $||\cdot||$, then $L^\infty$ means there exists a finite $M>0$ such that $||u(t)|| < M$ for almost every $t$

Comment: Thank you, if the outer notation is changed, say $u \in L^{2} (0,T;H^{1})$, does that mean that the square of the norm is finite. i.e. $\| u \|^{2} <M$

Comment: @Randa : For your comment: $\int_{0}^{T}\|u(t)\|^{2}_{H^{1}}\,dt < \infty$.

Comment: @Liu Gang: to be precise, one only needs $u(t)\in H^1$ for almost all $t\in[0,T]$.

Comment: @Capublanca Indeed. Another way to deal with $u(t) \not\in H^1$ is to say it takes an arbitrary value in $H^1$